# Simple App To Post To Users Wall (Facebook PHP SDK 4)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have been searching for code examples and reading the Facebook PHP API documentation but I'm still a little bit confused when it comes down to sessions and storing the tokens.

This is the following code that I have (under submit.php):

```
<?php    
session_start();

require_once('Facebook_SDK/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once('Facebook_SDK/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once('Facebook_SDK/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
require_once('Facebook_SDK/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php');
require_once('Facebook_SDK/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php');
require_once('Facebook_SDK/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
require_once('Facebook_SDK/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php');
require_once('Facebook_SDK/Facebook/GraphObject.php');
require_once('Facebook_SDK/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php');
require_once('Facebook_SDK/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once('Facebook_SDK/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');
require_once('Facebook_SDK/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once('Facebook_SDK/Facebook/GraphUser.php');

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

$app_id = 'xxxxx';
$app_secret = 'xxxxx';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);

// Use one of the helper classes to get a FacebookSession object.
//   FacebookRedirectLoginHelper
//   FacebookCanvasLoginHelper
//   FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper
// or create a FacebookSession with a valid access token:
//$session = new FacebookSession('access-token-here');   
?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $app_url = 'http://1.1.1.1/submit.php';

    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($app_url, $app_id, $app_secret);

    try {
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    }

    catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) { } 
    catch(\Exception $ex) { }

    $loggedIn = false;

    if (isset($session)){
        if ($session) {
            $loggedIn = true;
            try {

                // Logged in
                $request = new FacebookRequest($session,'POST','/me/feed', array ('message' => 'This is a test message', 'scope' => 'publish_actions',));

                $response = $request->execute();
                $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
                /* handle the result */ 

            } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

                echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
                echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
            }    
        }
    }

    if (!$loggedIn){
      $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
      echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>Login</a>";
    }
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Then, I have this code under index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Facebook API Post</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
</head>
<body>  
<form action="submit.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <h2>Post to Facebook!</h2>

    <label for="postContent">Post: </label>
    <textarea name="postContent" placeholder="Enter your post here..." rows="5"></textarea>

    <button type="submit">Post To Wall!</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

For now, I'm not fetching the textarea content into the submit.php because I just want to test from within submit.php that the script can post to a user's Facebook wall.

The code isn't working and up until this point I have ran out of ideas.

The script does get redirected to Facebook for the user to login but then when it's forwarded back to http://104.236.247.219/index.php it just shows an empty screen and nothing gets posted to the user's wall.

Any ideas or suggestions and what I should do? I feel like I'm close but there's something I'm missing and my guess is something related to sessions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors displayed...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/hfeB8C7.png

Comment: I'm checking the apache log and yes, apparently:
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Facebook\\HttpClients\\FacebookStreamHttpClient' not found
Let me include the class